# Move to Previous input when pressing Left arrow in keyboad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the following is exist and working. This moves to next input on the right arrow key press

```
 $('input').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode==39) {
            $(this).next('input').focus();
        }
    });
```

But what i wanted in when i press left arrow key, it moves to the previous input. so that i am looking for `$(this).previous('input').focus();` is this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's `.prev()`

```
$(this).prev('input').focus();
```

https://api.jquery.com/prev/